# first time robocopy and my files are gone

Tags: windows, robocopy

I just tried robocopy for the first time and my folder is gone. This is the command I used:

`robocopy E:\folder G:\`
and then:
`robocopy G:\ E:\folder`

my folder at `E:\` is not showing. The used space is still the same as before I mean stuff are there somewhere but its not visible.
aw I have so many important files there

Comment: Look in the Recycle Bin.

Comment: @harrymc its not in bin. Partition E used space is the same as before this happen but command Dir wont show the folder

Comment: I use WinDirStat and now i can see the folder

Comment: Probably needed a refresh